# Delete 2 rows using IN () on a child table creates has match of 197 millions rows

Tags: sql-server

Why would deleting 2 rows using `IN()` on a child table create a hash match of 197 million rows, this query times out in the app, but deleting 1 row using `=` or `IN()` works fine and completes instantly?

Exec plans and queries:
DELETE FROM dbo.ClientDepartmentContact WHERE ClientDepartmentContactId IN (12126,12127)
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkKueM6HS

DELETE FROM dbo.ClientDepartmentContact WHERE ClientDepartmentContactId = 12126
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sku2lGaBr

The primary/foreign keys relationship are **not** set to to cascade.

DDLs:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact](
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DispatchContactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DispatchType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [DispatchContactType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientDepartmentContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_ClientDepartmentContact] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [DepartmentId] ASC,
    [DispatchContactId] ASC,
    [DispatchType] ASC,
    [DispatchContactType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Index
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientDepartmentContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_ClientDepartmentContact] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [DepartmentId] ASC,
    [DispatchContactId] ASC,
    [DispatchType] ASC,
    [DispatchContactType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact](
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DispatchContactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DispatchType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [DispatchContactType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientDepartmentContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_ClientDepartmentContact] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [DepartmentId] ASC,
    [DispatchContactId] ASC,
    [DispatchType] ASC,
    [DispatchContactType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Index
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientDepartmentContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientDepartmentContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientDepartmentContact] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_ClientDepartmentContact] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [DepartmentId] ASC,
    [DispatchContactId] ASC,
    [DispatchType] ASC,
    [DispatchContactType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DispatchContact](
    [DispatchContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](254) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DispatchContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DispatchContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ContactAddress_Email] ON [dbo].[DispatchContact]
(
    [Email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DispatchContact] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_DispatchContact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DispatchContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

SQL version 2012 standard, all stats are up to date.

Before asking for help, i have restored to the DB to a 2014 and 2017 (both standard) dev instance and cant recreate the exec plan, the queries exec instantly on those. The plan for the 2017 is:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJdpX76rH

Stats are updated via a maintenance job nightly, but I did update all stats while investigating the issue. I have tried adding index's using SentryOnes Plan explorer Index analysis tool to no avail.

ps Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use images to provide an execution plan; put it on [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and provide us with the SQL you ran and the DDL of your objects, **including** any relevant indexes.

Comment: @Larnu, exec plans are https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkKueM6HS
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sku2lGaBr. There are only clustered indexes on the primary keys

Comment: Still need that DDL, SQL and indexes. Especially when we have no idea what your primary key is due to lack of said DDL.

Comment: Also, you should add those plans to the question, not the comments.

Comment: The plans show other tables are involved; do you have a Cascade delete on the table by chance? As you have only a Clustered Index on the Primary Key that would suggest why a scan is needed; it needs to get the values of the foreign keys for the relevant rows.

Comment: @gingeradam without the query it's impossible to guess what's going on. The execution plan shows it's not just a DELETE with a JOIN

Comment: @Larnu DDLs added no Cascade deletes.

Comment: It seems you have a lot of FK pointing to your table, which is why other tables like `Client_Department` and `DispatchContact` appear in your query. It might be that those FK fields aren't indexed, or if they are then problems might be with state statistics or others. I would also add what version of SQL Server you are running your queries on, for further help in analysis.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, there are no joins in the query

Comment: @Radu, There are clustered indexes on the FK's. I have tried adding other nonclustered indexes, the query will use either clustered or non-clustered but will always do the table spool/nested loop/hash match.